# Subtotaling in jquery function (.click issues?)

Tags: jquery

This function only subtotals my last value clicked when I use the .hasVal class with a radio button. Any ideas?

Update: Here's the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/SUKsM/4/

Essentially my HTML form has a fieldset with values:

```
<fieldset id="breadOptions" class="hidden">
    <legend>Select one</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="breadType" id="breadWhite" class="hasVal" value=".5,260" /> White (260 calories)<br />
    <input type="radio" name="breadType" id="breadWheat" class="hasVal" value=".5,360" /> Wheat (360 calories)<br />
</fieldset>​
```

An here's the script:

```
$(function () {
    var basePrice = 3;
    var totalCal = 0;
    var taxRate = .07;
    $('#total').text(basePrice.toFixed(2));
    $('#sub').text(basePrice.toFixed(2));
    $('#cal').text(totalCal);
    $('#tax').text((taxRate * 100).toFixed(2));

    $('.hasVal').click(function () {
        var price = 0;
        var totalCal = 0;
        var tar = event.currentTarget;
        var optArr = tar.value.split(','); //cost,calorie

        price += parseFloat(optArr[0]);
        totalCal += parseInt(optArr[1]);

        $(':checked').each(function () {
            totalPrice = (price + basePrice);
        });

        $('#sub').text(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
        $('#cal').text(totalCal);

        totalTax = totalPrice + (totalPrice * taxRate);
        $('#total').text(totalTax.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried without comma in your value?

Comment: Have you tried `+=` instead of `=` in your `.each()` loop? At the moment each iteration overwrites the previous value instead of adding to it. Also, you have defined `totalCal` in the inner function and the outer function.

Comment: @JonathandeM. There are two values that are comma separated.

Comment: @nnnnnn changing it this way throws of the math greatly.

Comment: I'm not sure how maths that is already wrong can be thrown off. You need to look carefully at your loop - at the moment it assigns the same value over and over, but what _should_ it be doing? (My guess is that the three lines _before_ the loop should be _in_ the loop, using `this.value.split(',')` instead of `tar.value.split(',')`, and then my previous `+=` suggestion applied to the line that is already in the loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your complaint that is when you click a radio button, you only get a subtotal displayed that reflects your most recently clicked value. Is this right? It would help if you posted the rest of the `HTML code` that you're using (I'm assuming that the sandwich has more ingredients than just bread).

For now, I've dropped your code into a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/SUKsM/ with a few changes.

Once you've explained a bit more and supplied some more `HTML code`, I'll be glad to help you further.

Comment: Have you determined if you want or are able to use HTML5 data structures?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of HTML5 data attributes for the price and calories like so:

```
<input type="radio" ... data-cost=".5" data-cal="260" value="white" /> White (260 calories)
<input type="radio" ... data-cost=".5" data-cal="360" value="wheat" /> Wheat (360 calories)
```

When you sum the total price and calories, iterate over all the selected radio buttons like so instead of just the current one:

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    price += parseFloat(input.attr('data-cost'), 10);
    cal += parseInt(input.attr('data-cal'), 10);
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ncCgu/

Here is an example if you can't use HTML5 data attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/z55rd/

Comment: It's going to take me a bit to test this, but I'll mark it off answered if it works! This is very helpful suggestion!